# Access is not showing the records I have entered through vb.net form

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am new in  vb.net programming. Am facing a problem in database handling. Am using oledb to deal with database, which is MS Access in my project. I am dealing with queries at the time. Now the problem is that my queries are working well on vb form but are not affecting the actual database. For example, when am adding a record, it displays 'record added successfully', the message I have used for my conformation, but the actual database is not displaying the record I just entered and even got the above conformation message as well. I have checked query in sql editor too, its doing well. I have checked locals in vb debug mode, all are containing correct values. 
Am not getting what's the reason behind that. Why it is displaying the success message but not modifying the actual database. Same is the case when am firing delete query, till now. I have not tried Update query yet.

Technology - Visual Basic.net with MS Access
Am using Access 2007 and Visual Studio 2013
Please Help by your suggestions

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Message displaying does not mean you query has been successful. Of course the message will display because you programmed it to display. Your insert query might have not been executed and then program just proceed to the next line which is your message. Possible reason is that there's a slight chance that you missed the command that is suppose to insert the data. Please show us some codes to know where the problem lies. Might be `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` or something like that.

Comment: @Karlta05 - Thanks for your response. Actually the problem was not in code. It was with the working of .net, which was, at the time, was not clear to me. But shortly I resolved the problem.

Comment: @MAC : I am new to VB.net Sir, but not to Programming. Obviously I have used Control statements. So, after firing query I checked the result of query and upon that I performed the desired action. So, basically it was not the problem of Programming. Anyways, thanks for Suggestion Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the problem was the gap between my understanding and .Net's working.
Here is the solution.

You can include database in two ways:

1.Either importing it directly to your project from the place, for example using drag and drop, or some other such method.

2.Or, by including it via using wizard.

But, the difference lies in connection string you use in your project, if you give absolute path of database, then you will directly see the alterations in database you have done using your application, even in testing and debugging mode via IDE.

```
    connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\xyz.accdb"
```

But if you are using connection string provide by wizard, for example,

```
    connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\xyz.accdb"
```

what the IDE will be doing is whenever you will be running project for debugging or testing, every time, it will copy the actual database, with its contents as well, in **/bin/Debug** folder. So, the changes you are performing will only be visible to that copy, not the actual file. So, if you want to verify with the database, like in our case, check the copy of database, which will be present in **/bin/Debug** folder. You will see the changes there. But, every time you run project for debugging, it will replace that copy with original one.

So, actually I was checking the original database file, not that copy, since the changes were only made to that copy. So that is why I was facing the above problem, not due to any programming fault.

Answer (score 0):

Do the controls on your form have the correct control source, i.e. the database table/query from and to which it should be reading and writing to?